# Selecting inaccuracies in a database

Tags: sql

I have a small database with high school football game scores where users can text a score in.

I need to find which score reports are potentially inaccurate or inconsistent (which scores have decreased since the last score post)

I am a little confused in how to do this given the data:

SCORE TABLE

```
create table FINAL_score
    ( scoreID varchar2(10) primary key,
    gameID varchar2(5) REFERENCES FINAL_game(gameID),
    userID varchar2(5) REFERENCES FINAL_user(userID),
    curtime timestamp,
    qtr number(1),
    hscore number(2) not null,
    ascore number(2) not null);


insert into FINAL_score values ('s001', 'g001', 'u001', '10-DEC-12 02:10:00', 1, 7, 3);
insert into FINAL_score values ('s002', 'g001', 'u002', '10-DEC-12 02:12:00', 1, 7, 3);
insert into FINAL_score values ('s003', 'g001', 'u001', '10-DEC-12 02:15:00', 1, 7, 10);
insert into FINAL_score values ('s004', 'g001', 'u002', '10-DEC-12 02:28:00', 2, 14,13);
insert into FINAL_score values ('s005', 'g001', 'u001', '10-DEC-12 02:30:00', 2, 14,16);
insert into FINAL_score values ('s006', 'g001', 'u001', '10-DEC-12 02:55:00', 3, 14,19);
insert into FINAL_score values ('s007', 'g001', 'u002', '10-DEC-12 02:57:00', 3, 14,16);
insert into FINAL_score values ('s008', 'g001', 'u001', '10-DEC-12 03:15:00', 4, 17,26);
insert into FINAL_score values ('s009', 'g001', 'u002', '10-DEC-12 03:30:00', 4, 20, 29);
```

^he 7th insert statement is the inconsistency.

So far I have:

```
select *
from FINAL_score
order by hscore, ascore, curtime;
```

which orders them.

I just need to remove scoreID 6

Comment: Are you just asking how to delete the row with scoreID s006?  Or is it more complicated than that?

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using, some (Oracle, Postgres, SQL Server etc) have specific functions that can help you. Other's don't so it's important to know which you are using in order to get the best possible answer. Also, I think you mean you need to remove scoreID 7?

Comment: You can ask for the largest value in a column, at least in Sqlite

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way that you can get all scores that are less than an earlier score in the game:

```
select fs.*
from Final_Score fs
where fs.hscore < (select max(fs.hscore) from Final_Score fs2 where fs2.gameid = fs.gameid and and fs2.qtr <= f22.qtr fs2.timestamp < fs.timestamp)
```

Then, repeat the same thing for ascore.